# find exact number in text field in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays, where-clause

I am trying to query exact number in array inside text field in sql
so for example

```
SELECT tbl_campaigns.s_id,a_list_fk_i_id_tbl_affiliates
FROM tbl_campaigns
WHERE a_list_fk_i_id_tbl_affiliates LIKE '%1%'
```

can return

```
[3,8,7,11]
```

which is not good because i would like to get the arrays that contain 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use JSON functions:

```
SELECT s_id,a_list_fk_i_id_tbl_affiliates 
FROM tbl_campaigns
WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(a_list_fk_i_id_tbl_affiliates, 1)
```

Comment: one more issue what if i need to run a few numbers so i need to find 1 or 2?

Comment: @biillitil: you would repeat the `JSON_CONTAINS()` conditions in the `WHERE` clause, like: `WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(a_list_fk_i_id_tbl_affiliates, 1) OR JSON_CONTAINS(a_list_fk_i_id_tbl_affiliates, 2)`.